# Terraform reports aws_instance created even though user_data failed

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

How to control user_data return code (bash script) while running `terraform apply` command.

I am running the standard `terraform apply` command to create an aws_instance. The resource definition includes user_data (bash script). The terraform log content is telling me

```
'aws_instance.xyz: Creation complete after 54s (ID: i-04de6d5dfd569cbd7)...',
'Apply complete! Resources......'
```

even despite the fact that bash script failed. What is the 'state of the art' procedure to catch this problem? I mean, as long as the user_data script doesn't succeed, the instance can not be considered as successful 'created' and completed in green color.

Comment: I believe that once the ec2 instance has started booting, Terraform considers it's job as "done".. user_data is executed after the first boot (and can in fact trigger reboots).  What exactly are you doing in the user_data that you need to monitor?  (in fact, AWS itself will consider the EC2 instance as "running" even if the user_data fails)

Comment: "I mean, as long as the user_data script doesn't succeed, the instance can not be considered as successful 'created' and completed in green color." That's your opinion, however that is not how AWS works. The user data is just a script that is passed to the operating system. You would have to check logs inside the operating system to see if it failed or succeeded.